# Connect git with VS Code

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-code

How to configure VS Code to work with git? I'm using the standard scm provider in VS Code. I installed git on my pc, initialized the repository in a folder, made some changes and VS shows that it has been committed but I don't see in on my github, and when I want to pull from git VS shows "Your repository has no remotes configured to pull from."

Comment: What's the output of `git remote -v`? It sounds like you haven't pushed any changes to the remote.

Comment: nothing outputted

Comment: In that case, see @dstrants's answer. Your remote is not configured. (this is something that will automatically be set up when cloning a repo from a remote in the future).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You first need to add your GitHub repo as a remote! To do this you can follow the [Official Guide](https://help.github.com/articles/adding-a-remote/).

```
git remote add origin https://github.com/user/repo.git
#optionals below just to verify
git remote -v
origin  https://github.com/user/repo.git (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/user/repo.git (push)
```

Then you can push your local commits with [official guide](https://help.github.com/articles/pushing-to-a-remote/)

```
git push -u origin master
```

You can add remote directly from **VS Code** as introduced [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/versioncontrol#_remotes)

Comment: I typed git remote add origin https://github.com/myUserName/myRepoName.git in the integrated terminal in VS. Now it shows on git remote -v:

origin  https://github.com/myUserName/myRepoName.git (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/myUserName/myRepoName.git (push)

but still no my repo on my github

Comment: You have to use the link to your own repository instead of the sample link  *github.com/myUserName/myRepoName.git*

Comment: I initialized it. Then typed: <br> git remote add origin github.com/myUserName/myRepoName.git <br>
git push -u origin master <br>
It shows that repository not found

Comment: You have initialized the repo **locally**. You just have to do *some short of the same* thing on the **remote repo** and get the appropriate link. Just follow [these steps](https://help.github.com/articles/create-a-repo/)

Comment: Aaargh, finally got it, Thank you so much! Is it possible to create repo via the integrated terminal in VS without going to github directly?

Comment: No, unfortunately not! But you only need to create the repo once for every project!

Comment: Hello Francesco, I suggest you should create a new question if you are facing a problem that is not fixed with the above solution

Answer (score 0):

You need to push your local commits to your remote. Check out [Git Status Bar Actions](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/versioncontrol#_git-status-bar-actions) and [Remotes](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/versioncontrol#_remotes).